# search an array of objects with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm having trouble working out a morphia query.
I have a schema like this:

```
{ authorId:12345,
  comments:[
     { userId:34567,
       name:"joe" },
     { userId:98765,
       name:"sam" }
  ]
}
```

and I want to find all records using morphia where searchId is equal to authorId or userId.

I've tried a range of things, but I'm not getting it.  E.g.

```
Query<Record> query = datastore.find(Record.class);
query.or(
      query.criteria(authorId).equal(searchId),
      query.criteria(comments).hasAnyOf(Collections.singletonList(searchId))
  );
```

I've also tried using hasThisElement, but that didn't work either.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `comments` is an embedded field, use the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to query on the fields of an embedded document. The mongo shell query

```
db.records.find(
    {
        "$or": [
            { "authorId": searchId },
            { "comments.userId": searchId }
        ]
    }
)
```

is what you need here. The Morphia equivalent would be

```
Datastore ds = ...
Query<Record> q = ds.createQuery(Record.class);
q.or(
    q.criteria("authorId").equal(searchId),
    q.criteria("comments.userId").equal(searchId)
);

//list
List<Record> entities = q.asList();
```